# specify data port in ftp (terminal or python)

Tags: python, terminal, ftp

I have to upload a file into an FTP server from a specific IP. So I have to use ssh tunnels to connect to the FTP server. For that, I use:

> $ ssh -NL localhost:7777:ftpserver.com:21 root@myserver.com

This way, I can connect to the FTP server using:

> $ FTP localhost 7777

And the command port will be 7777 to 21, and everything works great until I want to use the data port.

I need a way to specify what port I want to use for data transfer in active mode to create another ssh tunnel and pass it through there. (I know it's 20 by default, but I can't assign my local port 20! I need to use 7778 or something.)
I need a solution for both the terminal command line and pythons ftplib.

Comment: Hardly doable in terminal/shell. Smart firewall can do this on its own, when configured properly. But that's not a programming question suitable for Stack Overflow. If you want to make this a programming question on-topic here, I suggest you focus on the Python solution. Otherwise, please ask elsewhere ([su]/[sf]).

Answer (score 0):

the solution was using sshuttle instead!

> sshuttle -r root@myserver 0/0

this will tunnel my entire connection to go through myserver! thus all ports will be usable
now i can just use the ftp command and by using 'passive', everything works great.